# grouping by multiple fields and formatting the result

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm attempting to group all records by harness, and date. Then show the total duration for that date.

**Document structure**:

```
const testResultsSchema = new Schema({
    duration: Number,
    status: Boolean,
    start_date: Date,
    end_date: Date,
    harness: String
});
```

**Query i'm running**: db.ecommresults.aggregate(

```
[
  { $project :
     {
       _id: 0,
       harness: 1,
       duration: 1,
       end_date: 1
     }
  },
  { $group :
     {
       _id: { harness: "$harness", testDay: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$end_date" } } },
        "total_time" : { $sum: "$duration" }
     }
  }
]).pretty();
```

**I'm receiving the following output**:

```
{
        "_id" : {
                "harness" : "api",
                "testDay" : "2018-03-11"
        },
        "total_time" : 120
}
{
        "_id" : {
                "harness" : "api",
                "testDay" : "2018-03-10"
        },
        "total_time" : 120
}
{
        "_id" : {
                "harness" : "api",
                "testDay" : "2018-03-12"
        },
        "total_time" : 33
}
{
        "_id" : {
                "harness" : "selenium",
                "testDay" : "2018-03-11"
        },
        "total_time" : 306
}
```

**The format of the output isn't what i'm aiming for, i'm wanting something like**:

```
 "api" {
      { "testDay: "2018-03-11", "total_time": 306 }
      { "testDay: "2018-03-12", "total_time": 542 }
     },
     "selenium" {
      {"testDay: "2018-03-11", "total_time": 645 },
      {"testDay: "2018-03-16", "total_time": 444 }
     }
    }
```

I'm using this with node, express, mongoose, and then using the response in a react app. I'm looking to send the data formatted for ease of use in the client.

I'm super new to mongo (well really all of the stack i'm attempting to use).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongodb do not support dynamic fields at this moment so you need to enclose it in a named field. I have added the snippet see if it works for you.

```
   db.getCollection('groupby').aggregate([
       { "$sort": { "end_date": 1 } },
      {"$group":{
        "_id":{"harness":"$harness","testDay":"$end_date"},
        "total_time":{"$sum":"$duration"}
      }},
      {"$group":{
        "_id":"$_id.harness",
        "v":{"$push":{"testDay":"$_id.testDay","total_time":"$total_time"}}
      }},
      {"$group": {
          "_id": "",
          "data": {"$push": "$$ROOT"}
      }
      }
    ])
```

Which will output like this

```
{
    "_id" : "",
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "api",
            "v" : [ 
                {
                    "testDay" : "2018-02-23",
                    "total_time" : 60
                }, 
                {
                    "testDay" : "2018-02-24",
                    "total_time" : 180
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "selenium",
            "v" : [ 
                {
                    "testDay" : "2018-02-21",
                    "total_time" : 30
                }, 
                {
                    "testDay" : "2018-02-24",
                    "total_time" : 30
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Probably, should right a new post about sorting.. but! I've been trying to throw a sort in to sort each "v" by test day, but i'm not having any luck!

Comment: you want to sort the array ?

Comment: I added sorting for endDate. You can add -1 or 1 to change the order.

Comment: ah Ok, got it! I need to read up on order of operations, i was trying to sort at the end. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code to get the format you want in 3.4.

Add extra `$group` to get values by harness followed by [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) with [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) to transform the single valued array into named key value pairs.

```
[
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{"harness":"$harness","testDay":"$testDay"},
    "total_time":{"$sum":"$duration"}
  }},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$_id.harness",
    "v":{"$push":{"testDay":"$_id.testDay","total_time":"$total_time"}}
  }},
 {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":{
  "$let":{
    "vars":{"array":[{"k":"$_id", "v":"$v"}]},
    "in":{"$arrayToObject":"$$array"}}
 }}}
]
```